# Postgres cannot connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rake

Super stumped by why Postgres isn't working on a new app I just started. I've got it working for one app already. I'm using postgres.app, and it's running.

I started a new app with

```
rails new depot -d postgresql
```

and then I went into the database.yml file and changed username to my $USER (which is what it is for the other app, which is working). So now my database.yml file has this development section:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: depot_development
  pool: 5
  username: <username>
  password:
```

But when I run "rake db:create" or "rake db:create:all" I still got this error (in full, cause I don't know what's relevant):

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"depot_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"<username>", "password"=>nil}
could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `initialize'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `new'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `connect'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkout'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in `checkout'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block in connection'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:170:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:144:in `connection'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:107:in `rescue in create_database'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:51:in `create_database'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `each'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"depot_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"<username>", "password"=>nil}
```

I have tried

```
createdb depot_development
```

I have tried going into the psql environment and listing users (which included my username among them). In the same psql environment, I tried

```
CREATE DATABASE depot;
```

I've made sure that the pg gem is installed with bundle install, I've run "pg_ctl start", to which I got this response:

```
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
```

I ran "ps aux | grep postgres" to make sure postgres was running, to which I got this in return (which looks like it's doing OK, right?):

```
<username>    10390   0.4  0.0  2425480    180 s000  R+    6:15PM   0:00.00 grep postgres
<username>     2907   0.0  0.0  2441604    464   ??  Ss    6:17PM   0:02.31 postgres: stats collector process      
<username>     2906   0.0  0.0  2445520   1664   ??  Ss    6:17PM   0:02.33 postgres: autovacuum launcher process      
<username>     2905   0.0  0.0  2445388    600   ??  Ss    6:17PM   0:09.25 postgres: wal writer process      
<username>     2904   0.0  0.0  2445388   1252   ??  Ss    6:17PM   0:12.08 postgres: writer process      
<username>     2902   0.0  0.0  2445388   3688   ??  S     6:17PM   0:00.54 /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/postgres -D /Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var -p5432
```

The short of it, is I've been troubleshooting for a WHILE and have NO idea what's wrong. Any ideas? I'd really appreciate it, cause I'm pretty new to Rails, and this is a pretty disheartening roadblock.

Thanks!

EDIT -- Per request, posting the successful database.yml . It seems the difference is the inclusion of a password:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: *******_development
  pool: 5
  username: *******
  password: *******
```

EDIT2 -- When I add a password to the .yml file, then run rake db:create again, I get the same error. And I'm running Mac OSX Lion, and I did initdb and stuff when I first installed PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the db is up and running.  Are you able to connect to PG from command prompt?

Comment: You haven't given access to the database for any users. You probably want `CREATE DATABASE depot WITH OWNER your_username`, or `GRANT ALL ON DATABASE depot TO your_username`. You may also need to set a password for the user in PostgreSQL, if you haven't done that.

Comment: How do you do that? I've tried psql -h localhost, if you mean that. That's what I meant by the "environment" above.

Comment: Please post the same section of `config.yml` from the *working* app, with your credentials `***`'d out.

Comment: Just tried CREATE DATABASE depot WITH OWNER username, then did \q and tried rake db:create again and got a similar error. Should I be doing something else in between those two?

Comment: Sasha, check out the following to help with configuration ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/28783632/2678290

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In order to create a database , before starting the command pg_ctl start**

- you have to initialize the database cluster then only pg_ctl start shall be success full*

this can be done in many ways 
if you are running on Linux / centos with postgres 9.1

> service postgresql-9.1 initdb

```
service  postgresql-9.1 start
```

or you can do like this

```
$ mkdir -p /var/pgsql/data; chown -R postgres /var/pgsql
$ su - postgres
$ initdb -D /var/pgsql/data

# Starting, testing:

$ postgres -D /var/pgsql/data > /var/pgsql/logfile 2>&1 &
$ createdb test
$ psql test
```

Initializing postgres **initb** differes from os to os and postgres versions , if the above command did not work please have a look at

Comment: I'm on OSX Lion, and I already did initdb when I installed postgres. Do I need to do it again for every app?

Comment: no , it is a one time process , let me know the version of your Postgres

Comment: check if this dir exists **/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data** , if yes 
then **chmod 700 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data** 
after a reboot
**pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data -l logfile start** and then try to create a database , let me know the result

Comment: It doesn't exist! God, my computer's weird. I had this meltdown a while ago where suddenly my whole environment disappeared and I had to reinstall ruby/rails/etc, and everything's been buggy since. There's no PosgreSQL directory in Library what should I do?

Comment: Just realized I have a <username>/Library and a root/Library. At any rate, it's in neither. Which one should it be in?

Comment: better reinstall postgres-9.1 , since the dir /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data consists of postgres config files ..
please go through this link [postgres Installation on OS/lion](http://www.crosstown.coolestguyplanettech.com/22-database/28-installing-postgresql-on-os-x-lion-107) , you shall be sucessfull

Comment: please check the third image  [setting the path](http://www.crosstown.coolestguyplanettech.com/images/postgresql-install-directory-data-2.png) , you don't need to install and configure phpPGadmin

Comment: **<username>/Library and a root/Library** does this exist 
/PostgreSQL/9.1/data

Comment: Yes. Now that it's correctly installed, I have to rerun initdb and recreate the dbs in each of my apps that use psql, right?

Comment: Well, shit. Now if I try rake db:create, I get this: "dlopen(/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libssl.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libpq.5.dylib requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libssl.0.9.8.dylib provides version 0.9.8 - /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16944/discussion-between-user1408935-and-cc4re)

Comment: pleas do this also 
mv /usr/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib.BAK
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
host: localhost
```

to development works for me.

Comment: Well, this solution works for me, unlike the solution accepted by op.