# could not connect to server: "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have a simple web page in Ruby On Rails with postgresql database, but when I run sever I have this error, I don't Know that I do.
I use postgresql because heroku need that the aplication is in postgresql.

I work in ubuntu 13.10

The error is:

***PG::ConnectionBad
could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?***

I need help

thanks

Comment: Is your postgres server running?

Comment: Did you search for the error message? You will find a lot of information about that, specific to mac os x. Also, did you follow the instructions for postgres.app installation, assuming that's what you are using, exactly?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. I searched for the error message, but I didn't find any for resolved it.

Comment: I found a solution ->   Just create a softlink like this :                                               ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432    ->   after I have to change in the pg_hba in line peer for md5 in line local. in this link explain correctly this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge  -> restart postgres and my app run in local perfectly. I am very happy¡.

Comment: @mayrues Can you write your solution with more details? I have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Just create a softlink like this,this works for me

```
$ sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

for [more info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432)

Answer (score 2):

Also you are able to force stop and then force start the server

> `sudo service postgresql stop --force`
>
> `sudo service postgresql start --force`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure the `socket file` is located in `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`. To check that

```
$ cat /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

if result shows something, then the problem is anything else. But, if file is not there you need to check `/tmp` dir (specially for OSX `Homebrew` users)

```
$ cd /tmp
$ l

total 16
drwxrwxrwt  7 root   wheel   224B Mar 11 08:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root   wheel   192B Jan 23 18:35 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel    65B Nov  7 22:59 .BBE72B41371180178E084EEAF106AED4F350939DB95D3516864A1CC62E7AE82F
srwxrwxrwx  1 shiva  wheel     0B Mar 11 08:03 .s.PGSQL.5432
-rw-------  1 shiva  wheel    57B Mar 11 08:03 .s.PGSQL.5432.lock
drwx------  3 shiva  wheel    96B Mar 10 17:11 com.apple.launchd.C1tUB2MvF8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   wheel    64B Mar 10 17:10 powerlog
```

Now, there are two ways you can solve the error

### Solution One

You can change the application configuration to see for sockets at `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`

#### For Rails Users

```
# config/database.yml

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  # port: 
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8
  # min_messages: warning
  socket: /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

### Solution Two

You can create symlinks to the expected location

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/pgsql_socket
$ sudo ln /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/pgsql_socket/
```

Then the error should go.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error due to not properly configured connection to database, and exactly because of syntax errors in setting up environment variables i.e.

`MY_APP_DB= $MY_APP_DB_NAME` which is wrong, instead of `MY_APP_DB=$MY_APP_DB_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this that works for me.

`sudo systemctl start postgresql`

then

`sudo systemctl start postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

Review the postgresql.log file

Mine said `FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid"` already exists
So I removed the postmaster.pid file and restarted the service, now it's working

```
λ /usr/local/var/postgres/ rm postmaster.pid
λ /usr/local/var/postgres/ brew services restart postgresql
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have to do to solve the problem of s.PGSQL.5432:

First change the unix_socket_directories postgresql.conf path / tmp / by another route

and then updates the postgres and postgres load becomes, if you want you can put the path again, and with it and recharge the postgres normally.