# Postgres. role "root" does not exist. When trying to pg:pull database from Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Im new to Postgres and to Heroku. I am trying to pull the database from Heroku but I'm missing something simple. I did:

```
heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY_URL localdb
```

And I got the error:

```
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
```

Then I tried the same with "sudo". and I got:

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

So, it must be I'm missing some simple commands I can't find. Im on Linux, I have Postgres installed and working.

Comment: i think you have to create a user role called `root` in your `PostgreSQL` or `Postgres` not `Postgre`.....`create role root login `

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`createdb` is a wrapper around the SQL statement `CREATE DATABASE` and as such it needs to connect to the database.

By default all Postgres commandline tools try to connect to the database using the current operating system user. As the error message indicates there is not user named `root` in the database. So you need to pass the name of the Postgres superuser in order for `createdb` to be able to connect. This user is usually named `postgres`.

Another option is to switch the Linux user to to `postgres` if such a Linux user exists.

I don't know Heroku and I don't know how you started `createdb`, but the parameter to pass a username is `-U` (for all Postgres command line programs). So you'd need

```
 createdb -U postgres name_of_new_database
```

Comment: Your last command doesn't work for me. However, `sudo postgres` works (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/28783632/952234)

Comment: The last command gives me also `createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"` in Debian 8.7. You can do `sudo -u postgres psql`. You can create db directly in `psql`: `CREATE DATABASE masi` which works. @YaroslavNikitenko

Answer (score 17):

Try to use:

***sudo su - postgres***

Then createdb using:

***createdb name_of_db;***

Comment: `postgres@3a733ae6fd45:~$ createdb name_of_db;`
`createdb: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

Comment: @EugeneGr.Philippov, it might be an issue with how you installed your Postgres. Which operating system are you using? And what shows when you write the command `psql`

Comment: Ezrqn Kemboi: I later discovered that probably `docker-compose` with `postgres` creates a single role explicitly declared at the `.yml` descriptor and does not create any default roles like rolename `root` or rolename `postgres` if it has no explicit instruction to do so. It seems this way!

Comment: Ezrqn Kemboi: also, afaik you don't need to wrap `su` with `sudo`.

Comment: Ezrqn Kemboi: I have successfully logged in with that explicitly `docker-compose.yml`-declared role which was non-`postgres` non-`root`.

Comment: Happy to hear that @EugeneGr.Philippov. Since you are using docker, these comments will be good for people who face the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to `heroku pg:pull` specifically, you can specify the PostgreSQL user and password by specifying the `PGUSER` and `PGPASSWORD` environment variables specifically:

```
PGUSER=postgres PGPASSWORD=password heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi
```

If you want to specify the host, for example `127.0.0.1`, this is how:

```
heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA postgres://127.0.0.1/mylocaldb --app sushi
```

See [documentation for `heroku pg:pull`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-postgres-using-cli#pg-pull)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you need to execute `createdb` as the `postgres` user.

Run createdb (in-line) as postgres user:

```
sudo -u postgres createdb name_of_database
```

The command suggested by Ezrqn Kemboi, `sudo su - postgres`, *switches you to the user postgres* at which point you would need to `exit` out of that user to return to whomever you were before hand. This isn't great if you're running this in a script or some form of automation.

The command I suggested will not "switch" to the user and instead will run the command "in-place". My suggestion is more suitable for running in scripts.

Pick whichever you feel is better for your use case.