# Create database in postgresql from jenkins execute shell command step

Tags: postgresql, jenkins

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql start

su postgres

psql -U postgres -c "drop database connectedcare"
```

I am running the above shell command in the jenkins execute shell command.

## Got this error :

*psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"*

I then updated the /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf based on
[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge)

However the command just keeps executing and never finishes.

How can I create a database in jenkins shell command ( postregresql )

Comment: Read the manual section on "client authentication", specifically about pg_hba.conf