# FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "shop"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

What I did:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
CREATE ROLE shop CREATEDB LOGIN PASSWORD 'kurt1245';
```

Then I cloned a repository from GitHub (a rails application which uses pg), `bundle install`, edit `database.yml` to write my password and now after `rake db:create` (also `setup` and `migrate`) doesn't work.

`database.yml`:

`development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: shop_development
  pool: 5
  username: shop
  password: kurt1245
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: shop_test
  pool: 5
  username: shop
  password: kurt1245`

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the same error a few days back.

Edit the `/etc/postgresql/$version/main/pg_hba.conf`

You can check what version you're using in the psql console as `select VERSION();`

Inside `pg_hba.conf` change

`local   all             postgres                                peer`

to:

`local   all             postgres                                md5`

**[Peer Authentication explained](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER)**

> 19.3.7. Peer Authentication
>
> The peer authentication method works by obtaining the client's
> operating system user name from the kernel and using it as the allowed
> database user name (with optional user name mapping). This method is
> only supported on local connections.

Comment: Don't forget `sudo service postgresql restart`

Answer (score 9):

Please Add host to your database.yml file. Hope it will help you.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: shop_development
  pool: 5
  username: shop
  password: kurt1245

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: shop_test
  pool: 5
  username: shop
  password: kurt1245
```