# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, adminer

How can how to access postgres databases from **adminer**?

I have changed the password for the user `postgres`:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
$ postgres=# alter user postgres password 'secret';
```

Result:

```
ALTER ROLE
```

But I still get this error on the adminer:

```
Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

[image]

Any ideas why?

I have these two users:

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 root      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
```

But I did not set password for user `root` when I created it with this command:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --interactive
```

Output (**why doesn't it ask for password??**):

```
Enter name of role to add: root
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
```

But I still get the error on adminer:

```
Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "root"
```

**EDIT:**

THis is some bits of my `pg_hba.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

I changed `peer` to `ident`:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                ident

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     ident
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Then restarted my machine. but still no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge):

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

and then restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're using "peer authentication" where you want to be using "password authentication".  With the default pg_hba.conf, you can switch to password authentication by specifying a hostname, or "127.0.0.1".

See the [Postgres documentation for authentication methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html).