# Postgresql : Just added a new user, but now says "unknown user"?

Tags: postgresql

Still havent understood the basics !!!
The username "postgres" created initially, immediately after installation, allows me to log in. But later I added a new user "p2" with the password "123". When I try to login using the p2 username it doesnt work. I dont know if I am following the right steps, please guide.

```
revoltman@G41:~$ service postgresql start
revoltman@G41:~$ sudo -u postgres -i
postgres@G41:~$ exit
logout
revoltman@G41:~$ sudo -u p2 -i
sudo: unknown user: p2
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Earlier I had created the new user :

```
postgres@G41:~$ createuser -P -s -e p2
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
CREATE ROLE p2 PASSWORD 'md576be8f31b92b38740013f11b102caa1c' 
    SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN;
postgres@G41:~$ sudo -u p2 -i
sudo: unknown user: p2
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

If I type \du in psql to find list of all users :

```
                                 List of roles
 Role name |                      Attributes                         | Member of 

-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-
p1         |                                                            | {}
p2         | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Am I creating new user in a wrong way or my login method is wrong ?
If you want to know any other details please ask.

Comment: Please suggest a good tutorial/guide on the internet. I am totally in the dark about basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to connect to posgresql in command line you should use psql `psql -U p2 DATABASE_NAME`

Comment: I did...postgres=# psql -U p2 hr2; And I get....
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql -U p2 hr2;
        ^
What mistake am I doing ?

Comment: you need to executed psql inside your terminal, log out from postgresql with ctrl + D.  you need to see that revoltman@G41:~$

Comment: revoltman@G41:~$ psql -U p2 hr2 I am getting......
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "p2"
It didnt even ask for the password.

Comment: you need to configure pg_hba.conf file see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge

Comment: # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                    >>> trust<<<<
Changed from peer to trust. And it worked thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

`createuser p2` is creating a *Postgres* user named `p2`.

`sudo` is attempting to run a command with the *Unix* user `p2`.

These are two completely different things.

Comment: Then how do I login into the role "p2" ? ...and then create new databases.