# How can I connect to a database as another user?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Im currently creating an API for a school project and everything is working good. My setup is: Node v10, Postgres, Koa and so on...

I currently have this:

```
CREATE ROLE sa WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'some-password.';
CREATE DATABASE master WITH OWNER sa;
\c master;
```

When the init script runs in the docker machine the output I get is this one:

```
CREATE ROLE
CREATE DATABASE
You are now connected to database "master" as user "postgres".
```

So I did change the file to something like this:

```
CREATE ROLE sa WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'some-password.';
CREATE DATABASE master WITH OWNER sa;
CONNECT TO master AS main USER sa;
```

And I get a syntax error:

```
STATEMENT:  CONNECT TO master AS sa USER sa;
psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql:4: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONNECT"
```

I can't find anywhere in docs (or haven't look very good) how to connect from a .sql file to a database with an specific user.

How would I connect to 'master' with its owner, which is 'sa' from a .sql file?

Comment: One doubt, are you using SQL Server or PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Vivek, I'm using PostgreSQL. The first RDBMS I learned is SQL Server. That's why almost everyone of the admins/db owners I create whenever I use other RDBMS than SQL Server are named 'sa'. Hard to kill the habit.

Comment: Check out my answer posted below, if you still facing any issue then let me know.

Comment: There is no `connect` [SQL statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) in Postgres. To switch the connection in `psql` use `\c databasename username`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your answer was the one I needed! Super easy haha

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here my assumption is you have a SQL file called "a.sql" and contains the lines of code in the file.

```
CREATE ROLE sa WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'some-password.';
CREATE DATABASE master WITH OWNER sa;
\c master;
```

Now you are running this script using "psql" command line interface (CLI), so you get the message as below...

```
CREATE ROLE
CREATE DATABASE
You are now connected to database "master" as user "postgres".
```

Now, the thing to be noted that you have connected to database "master" because of "\c master" with user "postgres" because of you passed the credential of "postgres" user. Is I am right here then, If yes, then you have to pass the user and password for different user i.e. "sa" as below.

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U sa -f a.sql master
```

Now, it will prompt for the password of "sa" user, finally, your script will run and you will be connected to "sa" user.

Comment: Any command to change user session from one user to diff user with password in psql prompt?
Oracle equivalent:  `SQL> conn user/password@db`

Answer (score 50):

You can do this via this command in psql:

```
\c db_name usr_name
```

Comment: it causes this error: `FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "user_name"
Previous connection kept`
`

Comment: @OussamaHe You could fix this by modifying the file `pg_hba.conf` located in `/etc/postgresql/<version>/main/pg_hba.conf` by changing the part `local   all   all  peer` to `local all  all  md5`. For more information refer to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge).

Comment: I wouldn't change the pg_hba the way eng.mrgh proposes it, I'd rather use: psql -h localhost -U <user> -W, for local ipv4 connection.

Comment: Any command to change user session from one user to diff user with password in psql prompt, without modifying pg_hba.conf ? Oracle equivalent: `SQL> conn user/password@db`

Answer (score 33):

You can do this via this command in terminal

```
psql -d database -U username
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer tells you how to login as a user before you run psql prompt. But if you want to switch between users inside psql prompt, you can use \c (connection command)

```
\c "host=your_host port=5432 dbname=your_db user=sa password=some-password"
```