# PostgreSQL dbConnect to shiny app in ec2 instance

Tags: r, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny

I have an ec2 instance set up with my shiny app and my postgresql database, I want to get the shiny-app to read from the database

If I type `psql` and `\conninfo` while ssh-ed into my instance I get

```
You are connected to database "ubuntu" as user "ubuntu" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
```

When I use R in the ec2 command line and type the following, I can read from my database no problem!

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "ubuntu", host = "/var/run/postgresql", port = 5432, user = "ubuntu", password = pw)
```

[image]

However, when I put these same lines in my shiny app.R file I get

```
 Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
 RS-DBI driver: (could not connect ubuntu@/var/run/postgresql:5432 on dbname "ubuntu": FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "ubuntu")
```

I've tried so many different values for host like

```
host = "localhost"
host = "my ec2 public ip address"
host = "127.0.0.1"
```

for example and nothing has been working.
my security group for this ec2 instance has an inboud connection to port 5432.

[image: all my inbound connections on my ec2 instance]

could this be it: why is one file green and the other pink? the green one is the one that works (local) and the pink one is on my instance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the inbound connection open to all IP address?

Comment: I’m not sure, how would I know? Does it say somewhere on the inbound security group section on AWS?

Comment: difficult to explain, maybe this could help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: hmm I've added an image of all my inbound connections, but I don't think that's the problem because this app used to run on this instance without connecting to a database and everyone who had the instance public IP address could access it (with a password I created).. the problem lies in getting the shiny app to read from the database. Also to be clear both the app and the database are on the same instance

Comment: You also need to give access to your database

Comment: How could I do that? Do I have missing inbound connections?

Comment: you should find it in the security group of your database. It is similar to the EC2 instance.

Comment: Im sorry for taking up so much of your time and I really appreciate you trying to help me, but I’m not sure I understand. My database is in the same instance as my shiny app so they have the same security group because they are one instance. When I ssh into it I can see my shiny app and I can see my database but the shiny app is not connecting to the database. The host inside my con() function is not correct even when it’s “localhost” which I thought logically should work.

Comment: have you tried with `dplyr` and `src_postgres()`?

Comment: Just tried it and same deal. I can read from the database in R but not in app.R with the same error. I've added a picture to my question.

Comment: Can you add a minimum reproducible example of your shiny app? And 
are you running your app on your instance or local computer?

Comment: sure I'll try. I've been running it locally throughout development but there was an old version of it on the instance that ran by reading from text files instead of a database. Once I was done developing the version that read from the database locally I've been trying to get it and my database on my instance. Database upload has been successful and the R code img I put up though is from my instance, not local. I've found a difference in file color between my local machine and the instance.. maybe it has something to do with permissions?? I'll add pictures

Comment: I think I know what the problem is.. my user is wrong for the .lock file it should be ubuntu not postgres.. is it ok to delete these files? will they be regenerated when I try to run the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.. this is the same problem as [Getting error: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres", when trying to get pgsql working with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge)
except that I was getting a different error for the same underlying problem.

the answer that worked for me is the second one:

1.

```
nano /etc/postgresql/9.x/main/pg_hba.conf
```

change `peer` in this line

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

to

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
```

2. Restart the server

> ```
> sudo service postgresql restart
> ```

3. Login into psql and set your password

> psql -U postgres

```
ALTER USER postgres with password 'your-pass';
```

4. Finally change the `pg_hba.conf` from

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
```

to

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

and that finally worked