# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" (postgresql 11 with pgAdmin 4)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-11

I recently installed Postgresql 11, during the installation, there's no step to put password and username for Postgres. Now in pgAdmin 4, I wanted to connect the database to server and it's asking me to input password, and I haven't put any in the first place.

Any one knows what's going on?

Comment: From the docs: By default, when PostgreSQL is installed, a postgres user is also added. The first question many ask is, “What is the default password for the user postgres?” The answer is easy… there isn't a default password. The default authentication mode for PostgreSQL is set to ident

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me more about the default authentication mode for PostgreSQL, or any reference I can use. - @iLuvLogix

Comment: what's your os?

Comment: Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: pls see my answer and let me know if you encounter any further issues..

Comment: Just to note, the command `CREATE USER sysUSERlive WITH PASSWORD 'password';` actually created my username as `sysuserlive` (_that is in lowercase_).

Using this lowercase username in my application.properties, or when connecting to the db via cmd (`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U sysuserlive`) it then fixed it for me.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The default authentication mode for PostgreSQL is set to *ident*.

You can access your pgpass.conf via `pgAdmin -> Files -> open pgpass.conf`

[image]

That will give you the path of `pgpass.conf` at the bottom of the window ([official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-pgpass.html)).

After knowing the location, you can open this file and edit it to your liking.

**If that doesn't work, you can:**

- Find your `pg_hba.conf`, usually located under `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\data\pg_hba.conf`
- If necessary, set the permissions on it so that you can modify it. Your user account might not be able to do so until you use the security tab in the properties dialog to give yourself that right by using an admin override.
- Alternately, find `notepad` or `notepad++` in your start menu, right click, choose *"Run as administrator"*, then use `File->Open` to open `pg_hba.conf` that way.
- Edit it to set the "host" line for user "postgres" on host "127.0.0.1/32" to "trust". You can add the line if it isn't there; just insert `host all postgres 127.0.0.1/32 trust` before any other lines. (You can ignore comments, lines beginning with #).
- Restart the PostgreSQL service from the Services control panel (`start->run->services.msc`)
- Connect using `psql` or pgAdmin4 or whatever you prefer
- Run `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'fooBarEatsBarFoodBareFoot'`
- Remove the line you added to pg_hba.conf or change it back
- Restart PostgreSQL again to bring the changes to effect.

Here is an **example** of the `pg_hba.conf` file (METHOD is already set to *trust*):

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

**NOTE:** Remember to change the METHOD back to `md5` or other auth-methods listed [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) after changing your password (as stated above).

Comment: I set all the method to 'trust', because whenever I create a new database, the server won't connect. Do you have any suggestions for added security?

Comment: Anyway, I'll definitely upvote and accept your answer, this will help anyone with the same issue.

Comment: @Michelley What have you done so far? Did you set `host all postgres 127.0.0.1/32 trust` to your `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: Yes, I've set all to trust.
For your reference, this is how my pg_hba looks like:
'host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust'

Comment: I'm running into the same issue on Linux Mint (Ubuntu 18.04 base). I've followed these instructions but it doesn't change anything. Still get the same error if I try to create a new server using postgres and the password I've set up. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kajsa have you tried it via pgAdmin or manually in the conf files?

Comment: I've only done it directly in the files. However I've solved it now. For some reason I thought clicking on the elephant in the panel and choosing *shut down server* would be enough but restarting with `*/postgresql restart` solved it. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: When I take these steps it still asks me for a password for user postgres, and I still don't have one. Anyone know why that might be?

Comment: @DannySantos If you set up the user postgres as described above you should have a password assigned to the db-user. If your db is on a linux system, you could change to user postgres by `su - postgres` followed by `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'someReallyStrongPassword'` That should do the trick, if not let me know and I'll try to guide you through additional steps ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix I would really appreciate that, if I try and do what you say it asks me for a password. I actually opened a topic specifically for this, if you can help me out at all I would be really grateful, I really can't solve this! Here's the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754266/postgres-asking-for-forgotten-password-macos

Comment: I have followed the steps still I need password to enter.

Comment: Windows 2012 server

Comment: @DevError404 So can you tell me exactly what you try to accomplish? Do you want to connect to the SQL-server with the user postgres without a password-prompt or do you want to set a specific password for the client connection with user postgres?

Comment: Actually I m trying to access an existing database but I forgot the password and want to reset it. When I go through the steps as above, I am able to access the DB as I changed md5 to trust but not able to change password it is saying, only superadmins can do

Comment: I spent a few hours working on this. It worked thanks to you.

Comment: @NesredinMahmud At the beginning it can be a bit tricky to configure/set-up postgres correctly - it took me a couple of tests/approaches to get the desired results. I'm glad that it worked for you ;)

Answer (score 75):

Change the password of default use
`ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';`

Comment: When we install first time we need to set password for default `postgres` user

Comment: For every user that we add, we need to set the password.

Answer (score 61):

For Windows variant - I too experienced this nasty bug because of pgAdmin for my Windows x64 install of version 9.2. It left my production paralyzed.

In folder C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data or C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.**x**\data, you'll find the pg_hba.conf text file.

Find the following lines:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

and change METHOD md5 to "trust" like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

From Windows>Run type "services.msc" and <kbd>enter</kbd> find the right PostgreSQL instance and restart it.

Your DB security is now blown wide open! Heed the warning to return it back to md5 after changing the user password expiry time to say year 2099 for all the relevant users.

Comment: What is the significance of md5?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Significance of md5: From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/auth-pg-hba-conf.html: `md5: Perform SCRAM-SHA-256 or MD5 authentication to verify the user's password.` See [Section 20.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/auth-password.html) for details.

Comment: For Linux users in terminal type: sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart

Answer (score 30):

I have tried all the above mentioned solutions, trust me northing worked! I have resolved the issue by using following commands

1. **psql -U default**
2. **\password**

Enter new password:

Enter it again:

[image]

*my username is : default*

This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I'm still getting  a `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "default"
` error message

Comment: Thank you! I tried `ALTER USER user_name WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';` soooooooo many times and it never worked. Your solution worked! :)

Answer (score 21):

For Linux user try this

```
//CHECK POSTGRES IS WORKING OR NOT
sudo systemctl status postgresql

//THIS WILL ACCEPT PORTS
sudo pg_isready
sudo su postgres

//NAVIGATE TO SQL TERMINAL / BASH
psql

//CREATE A NEW USER WITH PASSWORD
CREATE USER shayon WITH PASSWORD 'shayon';
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked out for me when trying to add a new server in pgadmin and getting the message: "Unable to connect to server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "name_it"

Answer (score 20):

Note: CREATE USER is the same as CREATE ROLE except that it implies LOGIN.

```
$ psql postgres
postgres=# create user postgres with superuser password 'postgres';
```

Answer (score 20):

After successfully changing the master password

If you get the same error even after following the master password reset steps
Open your command prompt and execute

```
    psql -U postgres
```

It will ask you for the password, enter the new password which you set now parallelly open SQL shell(psql) and try again with the new password

Answer (score 13):

try using `psql -U postgres` if have put password while installing this is command where you have to use that. Thank you :)

Comment: saved me , but any idea why it isn't working like normal user id , pass scenario

Answer (score 10):

### Option 1: If you use `trust`

Better change only postgres to `trust` in the pg_hba.conf, then access your db with postgres super user and add other users and passwords with the power of the postgres super user, then change all other `peer` to `md5`.

The steps: In the pg_hba.conf, change

- `local    postgres` to `trust`
- do not change `local    all` to `trust`,
- instead change `local    all` from `peer` to `md5` - which means that a right password is enough to login.

See this solution in detail at [the second answer of 'Getting error: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres", when trying to get pgsql working with rails'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge/26735105#26735105).

---

#### Option 2: Use `md5`, no `trust` needed (recommended)

This way is even easier because you will need to change the pg_hba.conf only once:

1. Change any local user from `peer` to `md5`, usually:

- Change `local    postgres` from `peer` to `md5`
- Change `local    all` from `peer` to `md5`

2. Add a postgres pw with the power of your Linux pw only:

   ```
    sudo su postgres
    psql (or psql -p <port> if you have more than one PostgreSQL)
    \password
    \q
   ```

See [the accepted answer and the comments of "Getting error: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres", when trying to get pgsql working with rails"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664239/11154841).

Comment: Option 2: setting the password with \password did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I am not sure why this is not easily found. All of the documentation I found online simply instructs us to initially login to psql and issue "alter user postgres with password 'strongpass'" and then update the /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/pg_hba.conf file and change method from peer/trust to md5/scram-sha-256. Doing this DOES NOT WORK. Setting the password with \password is the only thing that works.

Comment: @waltmagic I also found it after trying and searching around far too long, it was in a comment of the link at the bottom of the answer. Only the comment of @mirek under it showed me this `\password` trick. I also commented and tried to edit the answer but it was refused, I think even twice. Not good. If I had not posted the idea of that comment here, you would not have the solution. And we talk about a post of >1000 upvotes and a ~1 million views Q. The other answer (first of the two links) was also hard to read, I had to edit it strongly to make it more readable, yet it had > 500 upvotes.

Comment: option2 worked for me too

Answer (score 6):

This particular situation I'm about to mention probably doesn't come up very often, but I was getting this error as well.  After looking into it, it was because I had a local postgres instance listening on port 5433, and I was trying to set up a Kubernetes tunnel to a remote PG instance mapped to local port 5433 as well.  It turns out the command I was running was attempting to connect to the local instance rather than the remote instance.  When I temporarily stopped the local instance, I was able to connect to the remote instance through the tunnel without changing the `psql` command I was using.

Comment: thankyou! Solved my problem which was, due to having postgress installed locally but trying to access one in a docker container.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by changing peer to trust in the file "pg_hba.conf" at local postgres then I restarted the postgres service with the command:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "superuser" password for the first time.

After that you can use Object > Create > Login/Group Role to change the password for the "postgres" user.

Answer (score 3):

I currently had a headhache solving this case. A friend helped me I decided to post my solution here.

1. Open pg_hba.conf in any text editor *(you can find this file in your postgres instalation folder > data)*;
2. Change all the methods fields to trust *(meaning you don't need a password for postgre)*;
3. Run in your console this comand: "alter user postgres with password '[my password]';" | psql -U postgres *(meaning to alter some user password for [my password] for the user as parameter -U postgres)*;
4. Et voilà *(don't forget to change back the method from trust for the one that should be best for you)*.

I hope this help someone someday.

Answer (score 2):

Follow below stepsif you are using pgAdmin4 and facing error in updating password :

1. Open file "pg_hba.conf" and find "IPv4 local connections"
2. See the value under "Method" column, it must be set to "md5" becase you selected it while installing.
3. Make "md5" value blank and save the file. Restart pgAdmin4 application.
4. Now again set the value back to "md5" and input your password in pgAdmin application.

You should be successfully able to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I wasn't able to  input mypassword in pgAdmin application again

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem, e.g. no dialog for setting password for Postgres during installation with Postgresql 11.

Instead of doing all the file manipulations suggested in the other answers, I deleted Postgresql 11 and installed Postgresql 12, where I was prompted for setting password during installation.

Comment: I was asked the password and I set it too while installing Postgres 12 but now the password is not being accepted and I get this error `psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "USER"` I am entering the correct password though

Comment: I'm having the same problem as Ananta K Roy

Answer (score 2):

- Loggin to PgAdmin4

Go to

- Object > Create > Login/Group Role
- Create the "username" that was named in the psql terminal
- Create password
- Give it all the rights
- Save
- try the password immediately in the psql terminal.

It worked for me.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Make sure you have PostgreSQL 15 selected in PgAdmin

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who got this error and NONE of these answers helped, I may not have StackOverflow fish for you, but I'll teach you how to fish!

You likely don't have the correct order of lines in the pg_hba.conf file.  If you read this PostgreSQL documentation link below, it says this error can be thrown if "no matching entry is found".  However, that is NOT always true!  Documentation is written by humans and humans make mistakes.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication-problems.html

The truth is that a line further up might take precedence, is qualifying and is forcing you to use a password stored in PostgreSQL rather than delegated authentication or some other method.  If you are not specifying a password stored in PostgreSQL, then you do not need the LOGIN role attribute.  Put a line at the very top of this list with your specific user, authentication protocol, network details and other criteria.  Also, many may think that most computers use IPv4.  Try IPv6 and you'll be surprised.  Once you know the very specific criteria of your issue and place a line at the top, then you have established the ONLY RELIABLE WAY to troubleshoot these pg_hba.conf issues without source code debugging!

Another helpful trick is to create a crapload of Server entries in pg_admin (SQL IDE for PostgreSQL) with all of your users and authentication protocols for testing.  When you test different scenarios, you'll instantly know which ones fail.

Also, whenever you change this file, restart the PostgreSQL service, before testing the user.

You're welcome my friend.  :)

Answer (score 1):

### windown 11 - postgres 14

1. open pgAdmin4 - click servers
2. right-click on your windows user name rule, e.g: MyUserName.
3. definition tab - enter password, click save.
4. open/re-open terminal
5. run: `psql "postgres:///"`

if you get "MyName database doesn't exist" you're good to go