# Postgres asking for forgotten password (MacOS)

Tags: postgresql

I'm completely unable to access anything in postgres as it's asking for a password for both the default `postgres` user as well as my mac username. I don't have a password for either, and in the case of `postgres` I don't even understand why there **is** a password as by defualt it shouldn't have one.

After running through many other answers on the subject:

If I run `psql`:

```
$ psql
Password for user <MY_USERNAME>:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "<MY_USERNAME>"
```

If I run it with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo psql
Password for user root:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
```

If I run it with `postgres` user:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
Password for user postgres:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Also in my `pg_hba.conf` all the methods are set to trust, have also tried changing to `ident` and `md5`.

On the advice of @jjanes I searched for other `pg_hba.conf` files and this is what I found:

```
/usr/local/var/postgres.old/pg_hba.conf
/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf
/usr/local/var/postgresql@10/pg_hba.conf
/Library/PostgreSQL/12/data/pg_hba.conf
```

The last one is empty (and read only) and the other three all look like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking in the wrong pg_hba.conf file.  If the method were really set to trust or ident, you would not be getting that error message.

Comment: @jjanes so that was in /usr/local/var/postgres but I also have some Postgres files stored in /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/12.1 courtesy of homebrew. I really don’t know much about this stuff, is there a chance that that’s the problem?

Comment: Also I checked in that directory and there’s a pg_hba.conf.samlple file but that’s it

Comment: The *.sample file would not be the one.  It is possible that postgresql.conf has set a name for the HBA file to be used which is different than pg_hba.conf, but that is not likely.  Can you use some tool like Linux's `find` command to search for any pg_hba.conf on your system?

Comment: I’m just about to get on a flight but I’ll check this on the other side, see if there are any other pg_hba.conf flies anywhere on my system. Thanks

Comment: @jjanes I've updated my answer with the results of the search. Essentially I've got 4 HBA files, three are all set to trust and one is an empty read only file.

Comment: @jjanes you have any clue? A week later and I'm no closer to figuring this out!

Comment: Can you find the postgresql.conf file for the running server, or the log file for it?

Comment: @jjanes I have the postgresql.conf file that is housed under /usr/local/var/postgres, yes.

Comment: If you intentionally introduce an  error into that file, does the server then refuse to start?  What does it have for `hba_file` ?

Comment: @jjanes introducing an error does not prevent me from starting postgres with brew. And in fact the config file is in located at `/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf` whereas the brew files are in `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/12.1/`

Comment: But I can't see a conf or hba_conf file in the brew directory

Comment: Also I managed to get the log open. Whilst putting the error in the conf file does not prevent postgres from starting, the log is filled with the error

Comment: After clearing the error the logs are saying `could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Address already in use. Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my Ubuntu 21.10.
I also tried resolving the problem by following the steps suggested above, but none worked.

At last, I resolved the problem by uninstalling postgres and removing every related files: https://askubuntu.com/questions/32730/how-to-remove-postgres-from-my-installation/32735#32735

Thereafter, I did a new installation of postgres using: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/installing-and-configuring-postgresql-on-ubuntu-20-04-e50122635927

Now, everything works fine.
Cheers.