# Getting back Server in PgAdmin prompts error "FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres""

Tags: postgresql, server, passwords, ubuntu-18.04, pgadmin-4

I have recently installed the PostgreSQL 12 and the PgAdmin 4 on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

Everything was fine, I opened the PgAdmin 4, it asked me for a password, I put a password `admin` and then I was able to see the main window in PgAdmin 4. Unfortunately, by a mistake, I deleted the Server that I could see via PgAdmin, and now I do not have one.

When I try to create a new Server `"PostgreSQL 12"` with a password `admin`, see image below

[image: pg_admin_window]

I am getting the following error:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

I have seen these threads: [Postgresql: password authentication failed for user “postgres”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres) and [FATAL: password authentication failed for user “postgres” (postgresql 11 with pgAdmin 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038942/fatal-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-postgresql-11-with-pg/55039419), but none of the solutions helps me, i.e. putting passwords like `admin`, `ident`, `postgres`, `password`, password of my Ubuntu account, an   empty password. Empty passwords prompts a notification

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Probably the PostgreSQL is running correctly, because I can see tables that I created for a project and I can also manipulate them.

A result of `\l` command shows:

```
postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges    
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres           +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres           +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 test_db   | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres +
           |          |          |             |             | test_user=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

A result of `\du` gives:

```
psql (12.5 (Ubuntu 12.5-1.pgdg18.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 test_user |                                                            | {}
```

And a result of `SELECT * FROM pg_roles` is:

```
          rolname          | rolsuper | rolinherit | rolcreaterole | rolcreatedb | rolcanlogin | rolreplication | rolconnlimit | rolpassword | rolvaliduntil | rolbypassrls | rolconfig |  oid  
---------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+-------
 pg_signal_backend         | f        | t          | f             | f           | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           |  4200
 pg_read_server_files      | f        | t          | f             | f           | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           |  4569
 postgres                  | t        | t          | t             | t           | t           | t              |           -1 | ********    |               | t            |           |    10
 pg_write_server_files     | f        | t          | f             | f           | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           |  4570
 pg_execute_server_program | f        | t          | f             | f           | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           |  4571
 pg_read_all_stats         | f        | t          | f             | f           | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           |  3375
 pg_monitor                | f        | t          | f             | f           | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           |  3373
 pg_read_all_settings      | f        | t          | f             | f           | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           |  3374
 pg_stat_scan_tables       | f        | t          | f             | f           | f           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           |  3377
 test_user                 | f        | t          | f             | f           | t           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           | 16385
```

Reinstalling PostgreSQL and PgAdmin did not resolve my issue as well.

So, my question is how can I resolve the problem I am facing to be able to see my tables in PgAdmin?

Comment: In`psql` what does `\du` show? Also `select * from pg_roles`? Please copy and paste the results as text to your question.  Images should no be used to convey textual information.

Comment: The password you enter during PgAdmin startup has nothing to do with the password(s) of your postgres database cluster. Use the same credentials you use to connect via psql in PgAd Create-Server dialog.

Comment: @clamp, unfortunately it does not work ...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I realized that the port I originally set was different than the one I was trying to recreate. Switched and worked.