# postgres 10 Peer authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-hba.conf

I'm trying to log in to a database with this command:

```
psql -U user my_db
```

This is the error that gets thrown:

psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "user"

I figured it had something to do with my pg_hba.conf. I tried several things but couldn't get it to work. This is the relevant part of pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   my_db           user                                    md5
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    my_db           user             127.0.0.1/32           md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

I also get the same error when I first do `su - postgres`
and the try `psql -U user`

Edit: Turns out I was modifying the wrong pg_hba.conf. I solved the original problem, now I can log in like this: `psql -U user my_db`. But my application, which is running on the same device can't access the database with this pg_hba.conf. Checking the logs this is the line that shows up when my application makes new requests:
`2019-12-10 16:18:51.144 +03 [29570] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres", when trying to get pgsql working with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge)

Comment: @richyen I tried the same line, it doesn't work

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't use peer unless you tell it to.  The pg_hba.conf you show is not the one which is in effect.  Either it is the wrong file, or the server hasn't been restarted since the file was changed.

Comment: @jjanes You were right. It was the wrong pg_hba.conf. Now I can access the DB with psql -U user my_db, but my application, which is on the same server, still can't access the db. I'm editing the question to reflect my new pg_hba.conf

Comment: Your new pg_hba only shows peer for a replication connection, so I think it is still not a correct representation of the true pg_hba.conf.  What OS users does your application server run as?

Comment: No it's the right one. It's a fresh setup so I assume the peer method is the default. I solved my other problem it was related to my application's settings. Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you say you solved your "other problem," do you still have a problem that needs to be addressed here in Stack Overflow?