# How to push local django database into heroku database

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have created django project with postgres database I have deployed my project into heroku server, and also migrate with

> heroku run python manage.py migrate

I want to push my stored database to heroku database,

```
PGUSER=edpuser PASSWORD=1qazxsw2 heroku pg:push applications postgresql-curly-07168 --app application
```

but getting

```
> error   shiv@shiv:~/Documents/projects/django_related_project/zoedp$
> heroku pg:push applications postgresql-curly-07168 --app application
> heroku-cli: Pushing applications ---> postgresql-curly-07168  ▸   
> Remote database is not empty. Please create a new database or use
> heroku pg:reset
```

I also run command heroku pg:reset and again try again 
this time I got error

```
shiv@shiv:~/Documents/projects/django_related_project/zoedp$ PGUSER=edpuser PASSWORD=1qazxsw2 heroku pg:push applications postgresql-curly-07168 --app application
heroku-cli: Pushing edpapplication ---> postgresql-curly-07168
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "application" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "edpuser"
pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from input file: end of file
 ▸    pg_dump errored with 1
```

here is my **setting.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'applications',
        'USER': 'edpuser',
        'PASSWORD': '1qazxsw2',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
    }
}

import dj_database_url

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

and overwriting pg_hba.conf deny me.
what should I do?

Comment: You probably want to use different user after resetting your database. Please confirm with heroku docs and your heroku settings what user is now being capable to write to this database.

Comment: I have the same exact error, have you found a solution? @shivshankarkeshari

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue, is more related to **postgresql auth configuration** rather than heroku **pg:push** command

I would recommend this approach:

Set a password for the **postgres** user:
Based on this amazing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735105/3172310

At this moment:
You have set a password for the postgres user and configure postgres to ask for id when using psql, which seems pg command does.

then run command as this:

```
PGUSER=postgres PASSWORD=pg_password heroku pg:push local_db_name DATABASE_URL --app application_name
```

Replacing:

- pg_password: password for the postgres user
- local_db_name: your local database
- application_name: heroku app name

and should work fine!