# psql version different depending on how you check it

Tags: postgresql, psql

The system says it has psql version 13 in 3 places, but seems to be version 11:

The three places:

```
> psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.1 (Ubuntu 13.1-1.pgdg20.04+1)

> pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 13.1 (Ubuntu 13.1-1.pgdg20.04+1)

> psql -U postgres               
psql (13.1 (Ubuntu 13.1-1.pgdg20.04+1), server 11.10 (Ubuntu 11.10-1.pgdg20.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

In postgres if I run `SELECT version();` it says 11:

```
postgres=# SELECT version();
                                                              version                                                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.10 (Ubuntu 11.10-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

I was getting [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge), but changes to `/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf` (**13**) had no effect on `psql` command, whereas changes to `/etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf` (**11**) did.

What is going on? Is there some strange nuance of psql?

Comment: `psql` != Postgres server. `psql` is the command line client. So you are actually `psql` v13 in all the cases, even the last one: `psql (13.1 (Ubuntu 13.1-1.pgdg20.04+1), server 11.10 (Ubuntu 11.10-1.pgdg20.04+1))`.  By default the Debian/Ubuntu packaging will use the latest version against all Postgres server instances as `psql` is backwards compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have two Postgres versions installed (13 and 11).

The PATH variable contains the binaries (`psql`, `pg_config`) for version 13, but version 11 is running on the default port 5432. Which also explains why you need to change pg_hba.conf for the version 11 to see a difference in the connection behaviour.

If you want to connect to the 13 instance, you need to provide the port for that. Try e.g. `psql -p 5433 -U postgres` - typically a second installation defaults to the next higher port number