# Rails whenever user implied as application name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, whenever

A cronjob generated on a Ubuntu 20 server by the `whenever` gem is failing, as the log registers:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "*name_of_application*"
```

The database.yml file defines

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
```

The application handles all migrations, records creations, updates, etc. as expected, so the connection with PG is proper.  However, it seems the whenever gem wants to connect as user *name_of_application*

Following the documentation and inline help, I ran

```
bundle exec whenever --user *name_of_linux_user*
```

to no avail.

The `schedule.rb` is as follows:

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
 
job_type :rbenv_rake, %Q{export PATH=/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; \
                         cd :path && :environment_variable=:environment :bundle_command rake :task --silent :output }

job_type :rbenv_runner, %Q{export PATH=/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; \
                         cd :path && :bundle_command :runner_command -e :environment ':task' :output }


  every 1.day, :at => '00:22 am' do
    rake "cleanup:promos", :output => "log/sweep_log.log"
  end
```

Why is `whenever`defaulting to the application's name and how should this be corrected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres", when trying to get pgsql working with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge)

Comment: I have attempted that; I restarted postgresql `sudo service postgreql restart` yet the log returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

whenever gem presumes the application is running in production mode, thus renders to crontab

```
cd /home/deploy/app_name/releases/20211025093952  && RAILS_ENV=production
```

That database had not been created, thus leading to the user connection error.

```
 && RAILS_ENV=development
```

solved this use case.