# Problem with PostgreSQL installation on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I followed several tutorials to install PostgreSQL on my Ubuntu 20.4, but I've a problem.
In order to install Postgres I used

> sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib

It seems ok, however when I throw

> sudo -i -u postgres

> postgres@gabriele:~$ psql

I see this error

> psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: >File o directory non esistente
> Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

I don't know how resolve this thing. Maybe, when I use pgAdmin4 to work with DB I find no server connection and I don't know how to connect a server.
It is my first time with this kind of things, can somebady help me?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want to start the Postgres database server in the background as a service (except e.g. in a container). It seems like you are trying to start it in the foreground instead.
You can do that using the following command.

```sh
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

You may check if it is running using this:

```sh
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

If it is running you should see something like this.

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2022-03-15 16:57:15 CET; 4min 34s ago
    Process: 205678 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 205678 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Then you will still not be able to connect via `psql` as by default configuration Postgres won't successfully authenticate you as it is using `Peer Authentication` and your username is likely not `postgres` which is the default user and database `psql` uses.
The error message will be something like this `psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`.
There is a guide on how to change the configuration in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664239/17487348) so you will be able to successfully authenticate.

Whether you're using `psql`, `pgAdmin` or another client should not matter as long as you have authentication configured correctly and are connecting with the right `username`, `database name`, `host` and `port`. You can see the defaults and how you can specify your own values using `psql --help`.

PS: You might also wanna consider using the official [Postgres container](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) instead of installing Postgres on your system. There is a description on how to get that up and running on DockerHub as well.