# How to correctly escape characters in command-line PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql, bash, command-line

```
[servername]# su postgres -c 'cd ~; psql -c "SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usename LIKE name;"'
ERROR:  column "name" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usename LIKE name;
                                                            ^
```

Tried vary ways but no one of them return the correct response.
May be there's a prettier way to do command-line queries?

Comment: Have you tried: `su postgres -c 'cd ~; psql -c "SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usename LIKE \'name\';"'` ?

Comment: Yep, it start waiting the input like if you just type 'command1 \'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
su postgres -c "cd ~; psql -c 'SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usename LIKE '\'name\'';'"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql  -c "SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usename like 'admin'"
```

make it two line.

```
/usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql test15  -c  \
"SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usename like 'admin'"
```

or

```
/usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql test15  <<<"SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usename like 'admin'"
```

or

```
echo "SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usename like 'admin'" | /usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql test15
```

percent sign still works.

```
/usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql test15  -c  \
"SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usename like '%admi%'"
```

Comment: The issue is that in one line I need to switch user and its directory, otherwise the command would not execute as well

Comment: @АлексейПашнин use to psql -U option.

Comment: I need to switch OS user, not the DB user

Comment: I know. it's hard. I don't know. one work around is `psql -U postgres.` after you are in psql then \! to change directory.

Comment: ex: psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "\du"
return: psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
so I don't need to use any password, I need imitate usual command-line usage via switching OS user

Comment: can you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge then can you try `sudo psql --host=localhost --dbname=database-name --username=postgres`

Comment: Last cmd asks a password input, and the way from the question above I saw, but I cannot change the config file

Comment: I found the way, post in separate answer here